# Why is $\int f(x)^{dx}$ an appropriate notation for the product integral?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry

Just as the title says, why is the product integral's notation: $\int f(x)^{dx}$ appropriate? I sort of understand the product integral, but this notation doesn't really make any sense to me.

Is this a consequence of Theorem $1$:

> **Theorem 1** If $a_k>−1$ for all $k$, then the infinite product $\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty (1+a_k)$ converges if and only if the infinite series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \log{(1+a_k)}$ converges.

If so, how is it a consequence and what is a proof of this? (I found this theorem on [How to go from a sum to a product and a product to a sum?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442924/how-to-go-from-a-sum-to-a-product-and-a-product-to-a-sum), which I found from a google search, so this might be the complete wrong approach at finding out why the notation $\int f(x)^{dx}$ works, but it's the closest I think I have gotten.)

EDIT: So I figure it actually has more to do with how $e^a \cdot e^b = e^{a+b}$ and $\ln{a}+\ln{b} = \ln(ab)$, but how come $e$ and $ln$ don't appear in the integral if you are using this property? Can someone just derive the notation using reimann sums or something?

Comment: What is you definition of the product integral?

Comment: Ok so it is actually abuse of notation to keep using $\int$ because it is not a smooth summation? If so that would basically be an answer and you could just drop it down below as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: I wouldn't say "abuse of notation." We model our integrals on $\sum_i f(x_i)(x_i - x_{i - 1})$. Likewise, we model our product integrals on $\Pi_i f(x_i)^{x_i - x_{i -1 }}$. Looking at the uniform interval case might make things clear. If we split up $[0,a]$ into two pieces of length $\frac{1}{2}$, the integral is approximated by $a\sum_i \frac{f(x_i)}{2}$, i.e. is the arithmetic average of two values of the function scaled by the width. The product integral  is approximated by $\Pi_i f(x_i)^{\frac{a}{2}}$, i.e. is the geometric average of two values of the function to the power of the width.

Comment: Right. I just wanna be sure before I accept an answer though, that writing $\int f(x)^dx$ is NOT implying summation of values of $f(x)$ raised to $dx$, but rather multiplying values of $f(x)$ raised to dx, the symbol $\int$ is referring to a different operation.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, you're right. We should perhaps write $\Pi f(x)^{dx}$ instead (this is the notation that wikipedia uses). The product integral is the limit of a product, not the limit of a sum.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll accept @GEdgar's answer because it was decently informative and the question has been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral) has a discussion of this.  That article (somewhat unusually) uses the symbol $\Pi$ instead of $\int$.  Other sources may use the $\int$ symbol or the $\int$ symbol  with a superimposed $\times$ or superimposed $\mathcal P$.

I think this is hardly ever used for scalar-valued functions, though.  As noted, you can do it instead with something like $\exp\left(\int \log f(x)\;dx\right)$.  When it is most often used is when the values do not commute.  For example, matrices.  Then the product integral can no longer be reduced to an ordinary integral using $\exp$ and $\log$.

For example, solution of differential equation
$$
\mathbf{x}'(t) = A(t) \mathbf{x}(t)
$$
where $\mathbf{x}(t)$ is an $n$-vector and $A(t)$ is an $n \times n$ matrix for $t \in [a,b]$.

Reference:

*Dollard, John D.; Friedman, Charles N.*, Product integration with applications to differential equations. Foreword by Felix E. Browder. Appendix by P. R. Masani, Encyclopedia ot Mathematics and its Applications 10. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 978-0-521-17737-5/pbk). xxii, 253 p. (2011). [ZBL1217.34018](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1217.34018).

Comment: An example of a differential equation where the product integral is not exp of log was just posted in MO.  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380959/can-we-solve-this-ode